# jquery remote validation modification

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have applied jquery remote validation. on success i have added an image against my textbox. but i want to remove that image  once the other validation applies because i have applied multiple validations . please suggest. following is my code for validation on email- textbox.
Jquery:

```
/*--Validations for registeration step-1 - starts here ---*/    
    var school_url = "/" + PROJECT_NAME + "registration/get-schools-list";
    var company_url = "/" + PROJECT_NAME + "registration/get-all-ref-companies";
    autoComplete( 'input[type=text]#college', school_url);
    autoComplete( 'input[type=text]#employed_company', company_url);

    $( "#registeration_step1" ).validate({
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
                noSpace: true,
                alphaOnly:true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
                noSpace: true,
                alphaOnly:true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                noSpace: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/"+PROJECT_NAME+"index/check-email-exist",
                    type: "post",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("div#tick-box-image").html("<img style = 'margin-top: 5px;' src = '"+IMAGE_PATH+"/loading_small_black_purple.gif'>");
                    },
                    complete: function(data) {
                        if(data.responseText == "true")
                        {
                            $("div#tick-box-image").html("<img src = '"+IMAGE_PATH+"/tick-white.png' alt='Ok' title='Ok'>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("div#tick-box-image").html("");                           
                        }
                    },
                    data: {
                            email: function() {
                                return $( "#email" ).val();
                            }
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                ilook_password: true,
                 minlength: 8,
                 maxlength: 20,
                 noSpace: true

            }
        },
        messages: {
            first_name:{
                noSpace:"Please enter valid first name"
            },
            last_name:{
                noSpace:"Please enter valid last name"
            },
            email: {
                remote: "Not available!",
            }
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<!-- Create Account Starts -->
<div class="create-account">
    <h3>CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT</h3>
    <form name="registeration_step1" id="registeration_step1"
        method="POST" action="registration">
        <div class="create-account-col1">
            <div class="create-account-col1-left">First Name:</div>
            <div class="create-account-col1-right">
                <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create-account-col1">
            <div class="create-account-col1-left">Last Name:</div>
            <div class="create-account-col1-right">
                <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create-account-col1">
            <div class="create-account-col1-left">Email:</div>
            <div class="create-account-col1-right">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="tick-box" id="tick-box-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create-account-col1">
            <div class="create-account-col1-left">Password:</div>
            <div class="create-account-col1-right">
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="join-now">
            <div class="join-now-left">
                By clicking Join Now, you agree to our <a class="text-purple-link"
                    href="javascript:;">Terms</a> and that you have read our <a
                    class="text-purple-link" href="javascript:;">Data Use Policy</a>,
                including our <a class="text-purple-link" href="javascript:;">Cookie
                    Use</a>.
            </div>
            <div class="join-now-right">
                <input type="hidden" name="created_from" value="ilook"
                    id="created_from"> <input name="signup_submit" type="submit"
                    value="JOIN NOW" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

server side script:

```
public function checkEmailExistAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $email_check = \Extended\ilook_user::isEmailExist($params['email']);

    if($email_check){
        echo Zend_Json::encode(false);
    }else{
        echo Zend_Json::encode(true);
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Show enough code to create a complete and concise demo.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  ~ Show the rest of your `.validate()` method and the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: I want to see the rest of your code, because want you want to do should not be done within `remote`.

Comment: Hi @Sparky I have added relevant code.

Comment: My answer stands.  Did you find it helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

The `remote` method is used to compare the form input data with your data on the server.  The server-side script returns a response which indicates to jQuery Validation the field is either valid or invalid, and if invalid, optionally returns a custom error message.  **This is all** the `remote` method should be doing.

If you want to do things when *any* of the rules are evaluated, then you should not be putting this logic inside of the `remote` method.  You need to use one of the many available callback functions that are fired when any rule is evaluated, which is why I asked to see the rest of your code.

Typically,

[`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) - Used for placing the error message within your layout.  By default, this is placed after the input element.

[`highlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) - By default, used for adding/removing the invalid/valid `class`'s from the element being validated.  Used together with `unhighlight`.

[`unhighlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) - By default, used for removing/adding the invalid/valid `class`'s from the element being validated.  Used together with `highlight`.

[`success`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success) - By default, this is not used.  Optionally, this is used to place the error message element on a valid field... such as when you'd like an "ok" message or a green checkmark on a valid field.

[See the documentation for all available callbacks and options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

[Look at the source code to see the default functions for these callbacks](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js).  *You can copy the default function as a template for your custom callback function.*

---

**NOTES:**

You absolutely do not need the `data` option in this case.   You can remove all of this...

```
data: {
    email: function() {
        return $( "#email" ).val();
    }
}
```

The `remote` method is being applied to the field named `email`, so by default, the value of the `email` field is *already being sent to the server*.

The `data` option is only used for when you need to send *additional* data along with the default data.  Like if you needed to send the value of a password field along with the email address.